# Jqgrid with dynamic colNames?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Scripts:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Widget/GetTestData',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    success: function (result) {
        var colModels = result.Json.colModels;
        var colNames = result.Json.colNames;
        var data = result.Json.data.options;
        $("#grid_table").jqGrid({
            datatype: 'jsonstring',
            datastr: data,
            colNames: colNames,
            colModel: colModels,
            jsonReader: {
                root: 'rows',
                repeatitems: false
            },
            gridview: true,
            pager: $('#gridpager'),
            height: 349,
            width:968,
            rowNum: 5,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            viewrecords: true
        }).navGrid('#gridpager'); //end jqgrid
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Seçilen kritere uygun veri bulunamadı!");
    }
});    //end ajax
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult GetTestData()
{
    var result = new
        {
            Json = new
            {
                colNames = new[]
                {
                    "T1","T2"
                },
                colModels = new[]
                {
                   new {
                        index = "T1",
                        label = "T1",
                        name = "T1",
                        width = 100
                    },new {
                        index = "T2",
                        label = "T2",
                        name = "T2",
                        width = 100
                    }
                },
                data = new
                {
                    options = new
                    {
                        page = "1",
                        total = "1",
                        records = "1",
                        rows = new[] {
                            new{T1=123,T2=321},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934},
                            new{T1=4532,T2=934}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
}
```

This code works. It fetch all data from server. But I want to fetch part of data from server, in per page.

When I write following,I can do that I want, But I cant get colNames dynamicly.

```
$("#grid_table").jqGrid({
    url: '/Widget/GetGridData',
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: 'POST',
    postData: { DateRangeType: date_range_id, MeterType: meter_type_id, StartDate: start_date, EndDate: end_date },
    colNames: ['Okuma Tarihi', 'T1', 'T2', 'T2', 'Toplam'],
    colModel: [
            { name: 'OkumaTarihi', index: 'OkumaTarihi', width: 150, sortable: true, editable: false },
            { name: 'T1', index: 'T1', sortable: true, editable: false },
            { name: 'T2', index: 'T2', sortable: true, editable: false },
            { name: 'T3', index: 'T3', sortable: true, editable: false },
            { name: 'Toplam', index: 'Toplam', sortable: true, editable: false }
       ],
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [20, 30],
    pager: $('#gridpager'),
    sortname: 'Name',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "asc",
    width: 968,
    height: 349,
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows", //array containing actual data
        page: "page", //current page
        total: "total", //total pages for the query
        records: "records", //total number of records
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "id" //index of the column with the PK in it
    }
}).navGrid('#gridpager'); //end jqgrid
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult GetGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
{
    IEnumerable<MeterReadingsForChart> meterReadings = MeterReadingManager.GetCustomerTotalMeterReadings(9, 1, /*DateTimeManager.GetStartDate(0)*/DateTime.Now.AddDays(-40), DateTime.Now, DateTimeManager.GetTimeIntervalTypeById(0));

    int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
    int pageSize = rows;
    int totalRecords = meterReadings.Count();
    int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

    var result = new
    {
        total = totalPages,
        page = page,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = meterReadings.Skip((pageIndex) * pageSize).Select(x => new { T1 = x.Name, OkumaTarihi = x.ReadDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - hh:mm:ss"), Value = x.Value }).ToArray()
    };

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

How do I make both of them together? (dynamic colnames and fetching data from server in per page)

**UPDATE** (Scenario)

I have meter readings every five minutes. And I grouped them hourly, daily, etc... Also I grouped them meterType ({T1, T2, T3}, {Reactive, Active, Capasitive, ..}, {...}).

For examle electric grid:

```
T1 | T2 | T3 | .... |
```

Energy Grid:

```
Active | Reactive | .... | ....
```

and the others:

I want to pass extra parameters (rangeType, meterType) with grid's defaults. And create the new grid values (colNames, ColModels and data). So How can I do all of these.

It can be a method that returns the grid colNames and one more method that returns grid data?

I mean :

```
1. public Json GetGridOptions{ return colNames and colModels }
2. public Json GetGridData{ return GridData }

1. $.ajax { url : GetGridOptions }
2. $.grid { url : GetGridData }}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want have different `colNames` on the different pages of the same grid?

Comment: Yes. Different page, different colNames.

Comment: My first problem is partialy fetch data from server. I think, I can do refresh grid according to getting data.

Comment: What you mean with "partialy fetch data"? Every response from `GetGridData` contain full JSON data from `result` variable. Small additional remark: you should use `pager: '#gridpager'` instead of `pager: $('#gridpager')` and add `gridview: true` option which improve performance. You can use `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false}` because you change only the property.

Comment: You don't fill `id` in the items of the response. Dose the data have some native `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic loading of `colModel` and `colNames` is practical in some scenarios. If you do this you create the grid inside of `success` callback of your own Ajax request. To be sure that you do this at the first time you should use [GridUnload](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) additionally (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920612/315935) for the demo).

By the way you can don't use and `colNames` and use `label` property inside of [colModel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) instead. In the case jqGrid will generate `colNames` for you.

If you need to change the column headers inside of `loadComplete` or `beforeProcessing` it's not enough to use `setGridParam` with `colNames` only because the headers are already created. So you have to modify the text of the column headers *manually*. You can use the fact that the column header will be constructed from `"jqgh_"`, the id of the grid and the value from `name` attribute from `colModel`.

If you would use the values for `colNames` in HTML form like `<span class="someClass">My column Header Text</span>` you will the same results as with the usage of `"My column Header Text"`, but you will be able more easy to find and modify the header.

You will still need to use `setGridParam` with `colNames` if you use [columnChooser](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser) for example. The `columnChooser` read current values from `colNames` and use it in the corresponding dialog.

Comment: I m sorry, could you read updated lines in my question.Also, Thanks for advices.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi: Sorry I don't full understand what you do. Especially grouping of results is unclear. I don't understand what data you want to show and how. What means the texts `T1 | T2 | T3 | .... |` or `Active | Reactive | .... | ....`? Is it header of the grid? What about the paging of displayed data? How many rows you want to display totally in the grid? ...

Comment: I m sory. It is complex for me too :). yes they are grid headers. I have more than one million data. there are electric, water,gas and energy meter results. if meter type is electric I want to display T1,T2,T3 or if meter is energy I want to display Active,Reactive, Capacitive, (and more twenty column). There are DateRange and MeterType Buttons. If user choose one these buttons, I want to re-create Grid.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi: If you have only the two (or some else) types of the grid you can create *all the grids*. All grids excepting one can be hidden. You can dynamically hide or show the grids very easy if you hide or show some *outer div* which contains `<table>` used to create the grid. The usage of `GridUnload` abd recrating can be another alternative. Two other answers: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5408195/315935) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5409356/315935) provide some other options, which can be used in some scenarios.